# JavaScript - looking for Standalone jQuery animation function/library

Tags: animation, javascript, jquery-animate

I would like to request Standalone jQuery animation function/library.

I found lots of libraries in the internet - some of them were complicated to use, some of them were OVERWEIGHT and some of them were unsmooth/rough/laggy/slow.

I wont post the libraries I found because I believe there's no need. Tell me only about something I cant find by writing "JavaScript Animation Library" in Google...

Thank you very much!

Comment: jQuery has [several animation methods built-in](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). If those aren't enough, you need to tell us exactly what kind of animation you want.

Comment: What do you want to do? What can't be animated with the .animate() method?

Comment: I probably didnt express myself right. I can do anything I need with .animate() method. I just want it without the rest of the jQuery code...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? i need the exact same thing.

Comment: @deweydb no, not really but 3 years passed since then. you might find one now.. I am going to search again soon and will let you know if I find anything

Comment: I ended up using this: https://greensock.com/tweenmax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're actually looking for a JavaScript animation library, not a jQuery one.

You'll find several lightweight libraries at http://microjs.com

Also, check out the $fx library https://github.com/agilemd/Fx

Comment: I already use $fx library - this is the smallest library I could find with easy implementation. The problem is that it is not smooth as jQuery animate is.

Comment: Check out microjs.com, it gives you a choice of both css and JavaScript libraries. css libraries like Emile should give you smoother animations.

Answer (score 0):

Go for scriptaculous. It is an open-source javascript library, intended mainly for animations.
http://script.aculo.us/

Comment: Saw it already. this is overweight. I can take jQuery and it will weight less.

Comment: Then the best thing would be to use CSS3 in your project... CSS3 has a lots of animation capabilities inbuilt.